# Custom cell don't appear in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

My custom cell don't appear in my table View and I didn't find anything to answer that.

Here's my storyboard that contains the TableView :
[image: Storyboard]

This is my listController :

```
extension MatchListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MatchCell", for: indexPath) as? MatchTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        let match = matchArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.configure(nomDuMatch: match.matchName, scoreFinal: match.finalScore)

        return cell
    }
}
```

(I've configured the dataSourceDelegate by storyboard)

the customCell identifier is correct and I really don't understand why nothing appears at launch..

Feel free to ask me more pictures / infos !

Edit :

This is the result :
[image: Result]

Comment: Have you set the `reuseIdentifier` for the cell in InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: where you fill in matchArray

Comment: Yeah sorry, done !

Comment: ... and what means "My custom cell don't appear"? What **does** appear?

Comment: matchArray is an array of Match (custom type) that contains 3 elements

Comment: What is happening when you display the view controller? What is being displayed?

Comment: IS it a remote call to fill the array or local

Comment: Change the `cellForRowAt` function to force unwrap the cell... `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MatchCell", for: indexPath) as! MatchTableViewCell` and remove the guard. That will highlight any problems with the reuseIdentifer. :)

Comment: "My custom cell don't appear ". That is not enough information. If you want help you need to describe, in detail, what's happening. Are you getting a generic cell? Are you crashing? Is your table view displaying with no cells? What have you done to try to debug it?

Comment: check your  array contains data or not when table view appears it may be possible that your array does not contain data when you remote call to fill the array

Comment: The array is a public let, it contains data.

Comment: Is `let match = matchArray[indexPath.row]` called?

Comment: yeah Larme ! it's called !

Comment: The table view appears because I can see the separators but my 3 cells are  not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

  return 100 // or any value 
}
```

or use automatic cell and set constraints properly in IB as it seems that you have a constraints problem and set this in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Thanks ! Was it ! I just tick off the automatic Row Right in the table view attributs.